Не удается получить доступ к сетевым типам
Пишу неткод на unity ecs(1.2.3). Нужно сделать систему с мониторингом подключений. Пытаюсь сделать систему по гайду
[UpdateAfter(typeof(NetworkReceiveSystemGroup))]
[BurstCompile]
public partial struct NetCodeConnectionEventListener : ISystem
{
    [BurstCompile]
    public void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)
    {
        var connectionEventsForClient = SystemAPI.GetSingleton<NetworkStreamDriver>().ConnectionEventsForTick;
        foreach (var evt in connectionEventsForClient)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"[{state.WorldUnmanaged.Name}] {evt.ToFixedString()}!");
        }
    }
}

но юнити выдает ошибку что

The type 'Unity.NetCode.NetworkStreamDriver' must be valid unmanaged type (simple numeric, 'bool', 'char', 'void', enumeration type or struct type with all fields of unmanaged types at any level of nesting) in order to use it as a type argument for 'T' parameter

Пытаюсь сделать через NetworkStreamConnection и SystemApi.Query, то же самое, при том можно видеть что они каким то образом уже находятся на ентити, при том не синглтон не через куери нельзя их получить. Почему так происходит? Может я где то не поставил какую то галочку или не добавил что то в свой асембдев?
P.S.: переместил код из примера в общую папку без асембдева и он больше не жалуется. Вероятно дело в авембдеве...
